# Update Permaklinks in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, slug

Specifically I am talking about the custom structure of Permalinks:

[image: Custom Permalink structure setup]

Well I noticed the list of categories names that are different when posts are made, the URL is different than the /%catagory%/ variable (or placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, goto the Categories list under Posts and change the Slug. This is what the URL will show, not the name category.

[image]